# JMeter, bearer token and webdriver. "The audience is not valid"

Tags: oauth-2.0, jmeter, webdriver

I am working on setting up a load test suite for a site which has an OAuth2 login mechanism  on another server (PKCE I believe it is), so when I click login-button I am tranfered to another site to perform the actual login, which then transfers med back to the main site.

This login site takes my credentials and in return gives the browser a `code_challenge` and some .js-files, from which I believe the browser later on create a `Bearer token` and place it in the browsers `Session Storage`.

This, as I understand it, cannot be replicated in JMeter alone, but it can be done if using `Webdriver`. Therefore I've set up a webdriver testcase in JMeter which performs the login and saves the used `state`, `code_challenge` and `Bearer token` in `JMeter User Variables` to be used later on in the load test (this all works fine).

The issue here is when I try to use the bearer token in a JMeter `HTTP(S) Request` I get the following error in response header:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience '<censored>' is invalid"
```

These are the headers for one of the `GET` requests with bearer token (which is previously recorded)
[image]

The bearer is collected with this piece of code
[image]

It doesn't matter if I'm using Firefox or Chrome webdrivers, the issue is the same.

So either I am trying to do something which cannot be done (re-use generated Bearer from Webdriver in JMeter), or I am missing something I do not understand. Help please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add [`Bearer`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6750#section-2.1) to the value of the [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header like:

[image]

Also I don't think you need to kick off the real browser, [well-behaved JMeter script is supposed to act like a real user using a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) so my expectation is that you should be able to extract the token using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and suitable [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)

For a single thread (functional test) the browser is okayish, but modern browsers are very resource intensive (one instances takes a CPU core and a couple of gigabytes of RAM) so when it comes to real load test execution you will need really powerful hardware in order to handle this authentication mechanism so it's better to stick to JMeter's HTTP Request samplers

Comment: Yes, `Bearer` is indeed needed and is previously added to the key (updated question) and they are present in the Authorization header.
I would have liked to do this without Webdriver of course (due to the maintainability and performance aspects), but I need to somehow generate the `Bearer token` on the client side since it is not sent to me from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue!

I had extracted the `id_token` and not `access_token` from the `Session storage` which of course was not valid as a `Bearer token`. They looked very much alike but was not the same, and I missed that.

[image]